# django - image isn't saving, all other fields are

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

When I update the user profile via the view everything is saving to the db except the image. The forms are validating but image isn't being saved. I can log in the admin portal and successfully add an image to an existing instance. I assume my problem lies in my html template but I can't figure out what it is.

**Btw I've read multiple similiar post but none I believe addresses my issue.

form.py

```
class EditUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    template_name='/something/else'

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'email',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
        )

class EditProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    template_name='/something/else'

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = (
            'description',
            'city',
            'website',
            'phone',
            'image',

    )
```

views.py

```
@transaction.atomic
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditUserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        form2 = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.userprofile)
        if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            form.save()
            form2.save()
            return redirect(reverse('accounts:view_profile'))
    else:
        form = EditUserForm(instance=request.user)
        form2 = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user.userprofile)
        args = {'form': form, 'form2':form2}
        return render(request, 'accounts/edit_profile.html', args)
```

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    website = models.URLField(default='')
    phone = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

edit_profile.html

```
<div class="container">

  {% if form.errors %}
    <ol>
      {% for field in form %}
        <H3 class="title">
        <p class="error"> {% if field.errors %}<li>{{ field.errors|striptags }}</li>{% endif %}</p>
        </H3>
      {% endfor %}
    </ol>
  {% endif %}

    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {{ form2.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are uploading files, you must instantiate the form with `request.POST` and `request.FILES`.

```
form2 = EditProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.userprofile)
```

See the docs on [file uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/#file-uploads) for more info.